# How to align main menu to center? Theme Uncode Child - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation, center, program-entry-point

I am using Uncode theme 1.4 and I am stuck on a small problem. My main menu shifts to left with 27.5 px and I can't seem to override that in CSS. Here's my website http://ralucacozma.com/

I've tried the following unsuccessfully:

```
.menu-primary-inner menu-smart sm {
left: 0px !important;
}
.menu-main-menu {
left: 0px !important;
}
```

Your help is highly appreciated!
Thannk you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have verified with your website, this css does override,

```
.menu-primary-inner.menu-smart.sm {
    left: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks fo much for the reply! I have added the above Css and it does not seem to work. The menu still shifts 27.5px to the left.

Comment: This is what I get with Chrome Dev Tools <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu-primary-inner menu-smart sm" data-smartmenus-id="14909559045084106" style="left: -27.5px;">

Comment: just checked again - it does seem to work - for some reason it took a while for the css to have an effect. thank you!